# Using Django ORM to aggregate over a generated series

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions, django-queryset, django-orm

I have this query, which I'm trying to recreate with the Django ORM.

```
select
    count(tickets.id),
    date
from
    tickets,
    generate_series('2000-01-01', date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), interval '1 month') as date
where
    (date >= created AND date < resolved)
group by
    date;
```

I think I'm close with this:

```
tkts = Ticket.objects.extra(
    tables=["generate_series('2000-01-01', date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), interval '1 month') as date"],
    where=["(date >= created AND date < resolved)"],
    order_by=['date'],
).values('date').annotate(cnt=Count('id'))
```

But I get the error:

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field.

When I reduce the query to this:

```
tkts = Ticket.objects.extra(
    tables=["generate_series('2000-01-01', date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), interval '1 month') as date"],
    where=["(date >= created AND date < resolved)"])
```

I can see that the value in tables is getting escaped and wrapped in double quotes (from `connections[app].queries`:

```
'SELECT ...
FROM 
  "tickets",
  "generate_series(\'2000-01-01\', date_trunc(\'month\', CURRENT_DATE), interval \'1 month\') as date"
WHERE
 ("tickets"."queue" IN (1,2,3) AND
 ((date >= created AND date < resolved)))
ORDER BY "tickets"."created" DESC LIMIT 21'
```

So is there something like `mark_safe` I can use to avoid this? I suppose I could create a stored procedure to replace the `generate_series` stuff, but I'd rather not alter the database if possible.

Comment: Have you tried executing those queries as [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/) and than mapping the results to the model?

Comment: JOHN: The results I'm looking for are just pairs of dates and counts, that doesn't seem to match with the raw() method you linked to which expects to be able to populate models with the results.

Comment: Have you at least skim through the article? Specifically [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Comment: Have you tried [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) ? Something like `generate_series($$2000-01-01$$, date_trunc($$month$$, CURRENT_DATE), interval $$1 month$$) as date`

Comment: Igor - I didn't know about dollar quoting, I think django will still try to escape it though. ... Tested, yup: `DatabaseError: relation "generate_series($$2000-01-01$$, date_trunc($$month$$, CURRENT_D" does not exist`

Comment: JOHN - yes I can just run a cursor.execute() query, but there's some other ORM type filtering I was doing and I was hoping to do it through .extra()